# If $G$ is a finite group and $P < G$, why is there a subgroup $M$ in which $P$ is maximal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

let $P$ be a $2$-Sylow subgroup of finite group $G$ such that $P$ is not maximal subgroup of $G$. My question is: why there exists the subgroup $M$ of $G$ such that $P$ is maximal in $M$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli The standard definition of a maximal subgroup $M$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup with $M \ne G$ such that there is no subgroup strictly between $M$ and $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt My bad, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This works for any proper subgroup of $G$. The fact that $P$ is a $2$-Sylow subgroup is irrelevant.

If $P < G$ and $P$ is not maximal in $G$, then by definition there is some subgroup $H_1$ with $P < H_1 < G$.

If $P$ is not maximal in $H_1$ then by definition there is some subgroup $H_2$ with $P < H_2 < H_1 < G$.

Continue this process step by step. At step $n$, we have $P < H_n < H_{n-1} < \cdots < H_1 < G$. If $P$ is not maximal in $H_n$ then by definition there is some subgroup $H_{n+1}$ with $P < H_{n+1} < H_n < H_{n-1} < \cdots < H_1 < G$.

Eventually this process must terminate, because the sequence of indices $|H_n:P|$ is a decreasing sequence of natural numbers. We will therefore eventually reach some $H_N$ with $P < H_N$ for which there is no subgroup properly between $P$ and $H_N$. Then $M = H_N$ is a (not necessarily unique) subgroup in which $P$ is maximal.